# Regex: Match a character that is unmatched in a negated set only a certain number of times at the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, I want to match (i.e. add to the result) a parenthesis ")" if it appears twice repeatedly at the end of the string, and unmatch it if it either appears once or more than two times. Probably the answer is to remove the parenthesis from the negated set and "use it somewhere else in a different way" — thus, I have attempted adapting this approach, without any success. Though, my regex is fairly big and tricky, so certain regex expressions "become useless" — from what I can tell from my experience, as I am not that experienced with regexes. So, here's my regex:

`/(?<![a-zA-Z/]+)(https?:)?\/{1,2}[a-zA-Z]\S*(?<=\){2}|(?<=[^:"'\]);,]))/g`

See, my efforts on accomplishing this are "at one step of success" as my current regex matches the parenthesis when it appears twice, but it doesn't when it shows once, but continues if it appears more than two times. To put an example:

---

**Example URL:** `https://docs.google.com/picker?protocol=gadgets [...] &nav=(("fonts"))`

**Results:**

`[...] &nav=(("fonts")` - doesn't match `")` - good

`[...] &nav=(("fonts"))` - matches `))` - good

`[...] &nav=(("fonts"))) [...]` - matches `)))` but does not with unwanted characters on the negated set - (kind of) bad

*..and so on...*

---

I have attempted through different lookarounds and quantifiers... "mixes" and ways, and have accomplished no better success than the regex I have written previously.

By the way, I don't want to use the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) characters on the regex — as I am using it on big and variate scripts, and thus I am using a global context; probably I am mistaken on this statement, so correct me if necessary — but if they are required — as I have tried on more simple regexes — I will not concern too much.

As [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) requested, here is the expected behavior of the regex with the aformentioned example:

---

**Expected results:**

`https://docs.google.com/picker?protocol=gadgets [...] &nav=(("fonts")` - should match `https://docs.google.com/picker?protocol=gadgets [...] &nav=(("fonts`

`https://docs.google.com/picker?protocol=gadgets [...] &nav=(("fonts"))` - should match all the URL (the original URL)

`https://docs.google.com/picker?protocol=gadgets [...] &nav=(("fonts")))` - should match `https://docs.google.com/picker?protocol=gadgets [...] &nav=(("fonts`

Comment: If you use `\S*` at the end, do you mean you want to end matching a URL at the first whitespace/end of string?

Comment: Do you mean to say the match should end right before the last `^`, `:`, `"`, `'`, ``\``? Try `(?<![a-zA-Z/])(?:https?:)?\/{1,2}(?!\S*\)\)\))[a-zA-Z]\S*(?:[^\s:"'\\)]|(?<!\))\)\)(?!\S))`, see https://regex101.com/r/bDelDV/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I use `\S*` to match any character that is non-space on the URL, so it attempts to match the URL throughout, excluding the characters, at the end of the string, on the negated set, since, on the scripts I am using the regex on, the URLs can come part of arrays, for example.

In any case your regex seems to work to my desire even if several characters on the negated set are missed, so I think you can put the regex as the answer. So I just I want to exclude the characters: `^`, `:`, `"`,  `'`, `]`, `)`, `;` and `,`. 

Hope this can be understandable.

Comment: Or, also try `(?<![a-zA-Z/])(?:https?:)?\/{1,2}(?!\S*\)\)\))[a-zA-Z]\S*(?:\b|(?<!\))\)\)(?!\S))`

Comment: I did more testing, and it seems to exclude all the URL if it finishes with more than two parentheses, I would like to match it until the first unwanted character on the negated set

Comment: Please add the examples and expected behavior to the question.

Comment: Ok, so it is even easier: remove the negative lookahead - `(?<![a-zA-Z/])(?:https?:)?\/{1,2}[a-zA-Z]\S*(?:\b|(?<!\))\)\)(?!\S))`

Comment: Thanks, now it works by matching the parenthesis as desired. On the \b, on my case, I have changed it to the negated set you provided before, with all the characters I wanted to add, and it works like I wanted. I use it to avoid it stops on a character I did not expect to stop.

It goes: `(?<![a-zA-Z/])(?:https?:)?\/{1,2}[a-zA-Z]\S*(?:[^\s:"')\];]|(?<!\))\)\)(?!\S))`

Comment: Ok, the first pattern in the answer contains `[^\s:"'\\)]`, a negated character class that matches any chars other than whitespace, `:`, `"`, `'`, ``\`` and `)`. You may add whatever chars you want to exclude there. If you want to add `]` or `-` , remember to escape them to avoid issues.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your help. Edited my previous comment with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can use

```php
(?<![a-zA-Z/])(?:https?:)?\/{1,2}[a-zA-Z]\S*(?:[^\s:"'\\)]|(?<!\))\)\)(?!\S))
```

Or, to account for any non-word chars,

```php
(?<![a-zA-Z/])(?:https?:)?\/{1,2}[a-zA-Z]\S*(?:\b|(?<!\))\)\)(?!\S))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bDelDV/4). *Details*:

- `(?<![a-zA-Z/])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a letter or `/` immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?:https?:)?` - an optional `http:` or `https:` string
- `\/{1,2}` - one or two `/`s
- `[a-zA-Z]`  - a letter
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespaces
- `(?:\b|(?<!\))\)\)(?!\S))` - either a word boundary or  a `))` string not preceded by another `)` and not directly followed with a non-whitespace char.